# Electronic visa having Old Passport number

Tags: visas, passports, indian-citizens, dubai, passport-renewals

I have Dubai work permit mailed to me by my employer. It contains my old passport number which has ECR stamp.
I then got a new passport issued without ECR stamping, but with different passport number.
I have both passports.

Can I travel to Dubai now?

Comment: Hmm so are "electronic visas" the same as "e-visas"?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I'm facing a similar issue but I only have the new biometric passport as well as a copy of the old passport. My passport allows me a visa on arrival but I'd like the immigration officer to stamp my passport with the work visa. Any experience of having the new passport, the UAE form with the old number, and a copy of the old passport? Thanks much

Comment: @gulshan did the new passport work for you. I have the exact same ecr issue with new passport

Answer (score 6):

Yes.  This is a common occurrence for visa'd workers in many countries.  I've done it myself with a UK visa.  Long story short, while your old passport may have expired, it doesn't mean the documents attached have.  And if it's still the same, the UAE visa comes as [separate A4 papers anyway](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130726004238AASJGt1)?

Anyway, the general process would be to take both passports.  You present the new one as your permit to travel, and the old one with the visa as your permit to enter the country to work.

Others online [confirm this](http://www.expatforum.com/expats/dubai-expat-forum-expats-living-dubai/210530-passport-validity-dubai-work-visa.html):

> most of my colleagues carry around two passports - the current one and
>   the old one with the Dubai Residency Visa in them. I guess just
>   because the passport expires, doesn't mean the Dubai paperwork does.

And [another one](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081220073124AASecJz):

> You will need to carry your old passport as well as your new one. Just
>   because a passport expires does not mean that any valid visas, work
>   permits and similar documents expire with it.