# For countries that issue e-visas, do any also take up a full page of your passport when you arrive?

Tags: visas, passports, terminology, e-visas

Even though I travel a lot I've never had an e-visa.

I just found out at least some countries that issue e-visas do not then attach a full page version of the visa into your passport when you arrive. Apparently I could've visited Cambodia on my way from Thailand to Laos without using up a page, had I known.

So is this the way e-visas always work, or do they sometimes supplement the e-visa with a physical full page one when you arrive?

Of the two countries I've either been to or almost been to, both Armenia and Cambodia require a full page visa for Australians if we get regular visas on arrival, but both don't seem to require a passport page if you get an e-visa in advance, it will only be on a separate piece of paper.

Comment: I've added the "terminology" tag since this question is kinda about what "e-visa" does and doesn't imply.

Comment: I don't know about all countries that use e-Visas but Turkey is another (corroborating) example where if you get an e-Visa in advance they just put an entry/exit stamp and they don't take up an entire page on your passport. And yes this is true e-Visa where printing out a paper copy and keeping with you is useful just in case something goes wrong but you don't need the paper. It is certainly not necessary to be appended to your passport.

Comment: @FixedPoint: Interesting. As an Australian I always get a visa-on-arrival, which is a "foil" attached to the passport, but doesn't take up a full page. It's about the size of a postage stamp.

Comment: Cambodia visa is great asset to your passport. Because it can be easily peeled off and used for covering up stamps that prevent you entering certain countries or prevent blank page being stamped...

Answer (score 7):

E-Visas, by definition, are electronic (that's what the "e" stands for!).

Although I can't say with certainty that no country that issues e-visas also places a visa "foil" (the full page sticker/stamp you are referring to) in your passport on arrival, I've certainly never heard of anyone doing that, and never seen it myself.

Countries that use e-visas will use the details on your passport to access their electronic visa system to determine your current visa status, and then generally stamp your passport only with the standard entry stamp that does not require a full page.  Airlines/etc that need to check your visa status will follow much the same process.

Some countries, such as Australia, allow you to specifically request a visa foil for an e-visa, but there is no benefit to doing this other than potentially being above to prove to a third party that you have a visa, and they charge a non-trivial cost to do it.

Comment: So do you think "e-visas" are the same as the "electronic visa" talked about in this older question? [Electronic visa having Old Passport number](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/24583)

Comment: Probably, but the "ECR" being discussed there is NOT related to the visa.  It's something put into Indian passports by the Indian government - not by the country that the person is visiting.

Comment: Yes I found the terminology in that question a bit confusing. I tried to find out what ECR was to see if it warranted a new tag, but seems they're not meaningful anymore.

Answer (score 3):

I have come across situations, mostly in South East Asia, where you can get an e-visa online but then on arrival it does require a full page sticker to be placed on the passport. Examples I've encountered include Vietnam and Cambodia. In all of these cases, the e-visa is merely a pre-authorisation that needs to be endorsed on the passport using a sticker, rather than a visa in its own right.

However, the answer is going to depend very much on what passport you have, because in some cases you can get an on-arrival visa in the form of an entry stamp, while citizens of other countries need a full page sticker. As such, I think this question is not answerable in its current form because: a) doesn't account for passport b) too many variables in asking for a list of countries that need a full page sticker despite having an e-visa.

Comment: But E-Visas, by definition, are electronic (that's what the "e" stands for!). d-; How dare there be two ways to apply the concept "electronic" to the concept "visa"!

Comment: The question is answerable and you've answered it. I don't need a list. All I needed to know was that if "e-visa" might sometimes mean you still need a blank passport page when you get there, that I should allow for that possibility when planning. If the answer had been that everyone uses "e-visa" the same way because it's a standard term that's not used when foils are also required, then I'd be able to go to countries with e-visas, even with a nearly full passport.

Comment: Vietnam do not do "E-visas". They do have a form of pre-approved Visa-On-Arrival that is often referred to as an e-visa - normally by visa processing companies attempting to rip people off!  The new Cambodian visa, despite being referred to as an "E-visa" appears to be a print-at-home visa that is emailed to you, although it's not clear if this needs to be physical stuck in your passport or not.

Comment: @Doc Exactly as you described it. The term "e-visa" has various meanings and as I mentioned, in some cases it's just a pre-authorisation for a sticker visa. However, getting the pre-auth is often simpler / cheaper than applying for a travel visa in advance.

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee I still haven't seen any (official!) use of the term "E-visa" to refer to pre-authorization for a foil being provided on arrival. Vietnam isn't. Cambodia doesn't appear to be.

Comment: Looks like at least in practice it's not safe to assume what "e-visa" means for now ...

Answer (score 0):

It pretty much depends on the passeport you have (from which country) and the country you're visiting.
Some e-visas are totally E (electornic) and some other are juste a way to substitute the traditional visa application way.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a "others are substitute to the traditional visa" ? The e-visa *is* a substitute to the traditional visa

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the Country. In some countries the e-visa is only a pre-approval for a visa on Arrival, in which case they'll put a visa sticker in the passport, while in others the e-visa is all you need, in which case you only get entry and exit stamps in the passport